# Netbeans - Java ME : Adding an emulator for a specific device

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I'm really new to Java ME and I'd like to know if it is possible to add a specific emulator , let's say a Nokia Emulator, so that I can choose that emulator :

- When I create

[image]

- or when I run the mobile application

[image]

As always any advice or help would be so appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't use any specific emulator myself, but I believe it's pretty straight forward. Simply download and install the Nokia SDK. Then you'll be able to select the Nokia emulator in your IDE (like NetBeans or Eclipse). Same goes for other specific emulators.

Answer (score 0):

You can have below options.

1) There are some emulators on developer Nokia webisite you can download them
2) You can use RDA from below link. It is online emulators.

http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access